# Rails: Validate only on create, or on update when field is not blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

How can I restrict a Rails validation to check only on create OR when the field isn't blank? I'm creating a user settings page for an app I'm working on and the problem is that, when updating using the parameters provided by the form, the settings will only save when both a password and password confirmation are present. I would like these password fields to validate on create no matter what, but only on update when they are provided.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

If you want to allow blank values use: [allow_blank](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#allow-blank) with validates.

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, length: { is: 5 }, allow_blank: true
end
```

If you want to validate only on create, use [on](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#on) with validates.

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :email, uniqueness: true, on: :create
end
```

To cover your case:

```
class Topic
  validates :email, presence: true, if: :should_validate?

  def should_validate?
    new_record? || email.present?
  end
end
```

Comment: `if: :should_validate?` is really useful, and highly customizable. Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

This turned out to be a little simpler than I thought. I changed the form input names from `password` and `password_confirmation` to `new_password` and `new_password_confirmation`. I added temporary accessors for these values in my model using the following line:

```
attr_accessor :new_password, :new_password_confirmation
```

I implemented a `password_changed?` method defined as follows:

```
def password_changed?
    !new_password.blank?
end
```

Finally, I changed my validations to:

```
validates :new_password, presence: true, confirmation: true, length: { in: 6..20 }, on: :create
validates :new_password, presence: true, confirmation: true, length: { in: 6..20 }, on: :update, if: :password_changed?
validates :new_password_confirmation, presence: true, on: :create
validates :new_password_confirmation, presence: true, on: :update, if: :password_changed?
```

I'm positive there's a better way to do this (this isn't very DRY) but for now, it works. Improved answers would still be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 13):

It is not necessary to change field names, will be enough to replace `:password_changed?` to `:password_digest_changed?` in your code.

```
validates :password, presence: true, confirmation: true, length: { in: 6..20 }, on: :create
validates :password, presence: true, confirmation: true, length: { in: 6..20 }, on: :update, if: :password_digest_changed?
validates :password_confirmation, presence: true, on: :create
validates :password_confirmation, presence: true, on: :update, if: :password_digest_changed?
```

Answer (score 7):

Please try

```
validates :<attributes>, if: Proc.new{|obj| obj.new_record? || !obj.<attribute>.blank? }
```

or add custom method names instead of attribute name.

Comment: I would use lambda instead of proc: `->(obj) { obj.new_record? || ... }`

Comment: Strangely, adding this validation seems to cause my length validation to fail, throwing the error: "Password is too long (maximum is 20 characters)." My validation looks like the following: `validates :password, confirmation: true, presence: true, length: { in: 6..20 }, if: ->(obj) { obj.new_record? || !obj.password.blank? }`

Comment: Yes @Jamie you can use any options with if condition .

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
validates :password, presence: true, length: { in: 6..20 }, if: :password_digest_changed?
```

The Bcrypt gem requires that password and password_confirmation are the same so you really only need to worry about one of them. On both, the update and the create the password_digest will change. Meaning that the validation is called on the create and it's only called on the update if the user updates their password. You should have js validation on the front end but this single line of code will protect the db on both the update and create. I have tested this myself. You could probably use custom validations on this but I haven't tried that myself. Late to the game, hope this helps someone.